# Is this Greedy Search or Uniform Cost Search?

Tags: search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence, greedy-algorithms

In the below Image, S is the starting point and E is the end point.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3sS1.png)

Now, the Title of the video says that its a Greedy Best First Search.

However, while browsing stackoverflow, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082559/19264782)

It says that `Greedy Search doesn't go back up the tree - it picks the lowest value and commits to that.` and the behavior shown in the image I provided belongs to Uniform cost Search.

So, why the video title says that its Greedy Best First Search?

Which one is correct, the video or the answer?

[Heres the YouTube video](https://youtu.be/dv1m3L6QXWs) for Reference